# Flash Builder 'building' html files

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, ide, flexbuilder

I'm using Flash Builder 3 to edit my Flex app, but I noticed that every time I make a change on the .html files (index.template.html for example), even if it's not in the IDE but with another program, Flash Builder rebuilds the whole project.

Is there anyway to stop this? Why would it need to rebuild the workspace everytime a html file changes?

If it was too long it wouldn't bother me, but it takes a lot of time (more than 1 minute) every time. For your information the html file is 95 lines of 'code'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's the HTMLWrapper that takes a long time for compiling.

If you encounter the same problem, you can deactivate the wrapper generation in the compiler option.

Answer (score 0):

In the main application menu, make sure Project->Build Automatically is unchecked. That will stop it from automatically rebuilding your project every time a file changes.

Comment: That's not the problem actually. If I uncheck this it will only take longer when I compile...

Comment: The problem is when I only modify a html file. It looks like Flex Builder make a copy of it in the bin-debug folder, but it's _way_ too long.

Answer (score 0):

Ive written a short article about how to edit index.template.html so that your swf will centre on the page similar to Flashdevelop centering. You might find that useful, I wrote it mainly to explain to myself and the technique works fine.

See
http://www.thumbleaf.com/journal/?p=239

, Thomas